# Apache HtAccess AddHandler Conditional on servername or ip

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm hosting my staging and production servers at Site5, a relatively good hoster IMO. The question is not about their quality but more about an issue related to PHP's version.

Our development server is using PHP 5.3 which is a good version, 5.4 being too new, we don't want to use it's features yet, not enough widespread.

Problem is, Site5 uses PHP 5.2 by default but you can change to 5.3 using an HTACCESS AddHandler statement. Works fine on Site5 but our dev server crashes when we keep that statement in the HTAccess file.

If you use SVN/Git to deploy your web apps, you know that you always keep the same files everywhere, so thats where it hurts, i can't seem to find anything about conditional statements for HTACCESS files for AddHandler. I can write conditions on the rewrite engine easily, but i can't find anything that would look and act like this:

```
#<If SERVERNAME == "targethost.com">
#    PHP 5.3 configuration for site5
#    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
#</If>
```

Anyone has a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Apache 2.4 you can use this expression in your .htaccess files:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'example.com'">
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
</If>
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#examples

Note that this does not work in Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and couldn't find a solution within .htaccess. You've probably seen [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/22738/conditional-addhandler-directive) kind of solution, but it didn't work for me.

Since I use Capistrano to deploy my apps on Site5 hosting, I decided to alter .htaccess each time the deployment has done by adding a line to my deployment settings file which simply run a shell command:

```
run "echo 'AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php' >> #{release_path}/public/.htaccess"
```

Note: #{release_path} is my app's root path.

I asked Site5 support about this, but unfortunately they couldn't suggest me one.

Comment: Thanks! Works for me :)

Comment: @RonaldAraújo I'm glad this old post helped you!