# Multiple php versions with .htaccess files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cgi, cpanel

My webhost is offering multiple php version (running as FastCGI), ranging from 5.4 to 7.1, located inside /opt/alt/php5.X directory that can be used one at a time acting on cPanel Php selector.

Actually they don't officially offer the possibility to run at the same time multiple version of php (e.g. php 5.6 for one domain and php 7.1 for one of its subdir) either using .htaccess or other config file.

There is any way that I can circumvent this limitation knowing the path to the desired php version and using .htaccess or php.ini files ?

I've tried with the

`AddHandler application/x-httpd-php71 .php`

in .htaccess with non results.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857939/conditional-php-version-in-htaccess and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server

Comment: That depends entirely on how it was set up. If they're using a FasCGI/FPM setup, it's perhaps redirectable. `ProxyPassMatch` ought to work in per-dir config files. Better yet have your host set a secondary rule with e.g. `.+\.php7` matches

Comment: @GillesLesire thanks, I've solved using your first suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional php version by configuring the htaccess as explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857939/conditional-php-version-in-htaccess). A list of PHP versions can be found in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server).